# The role of puts in expect, script hangs after puts

Tags: expect

I'm new to expect and learning from somebody's script. There is a block like this after the ssh command,

```
expect {
   "Password:"    {puts stderr "Wrong password."; exit 1}
   "Last login:"  {puts "Login Successful."}
   timeout        abort
}
```

Well, a problem of this in my case is that if this is the first login to the machine, there won't be a "Last login" showing up. So what I did  was to add something and thought this might work

```
expect {
   "Password:"    {puts stderr "Wrong password."; exit 1}
   "Last login:"  {puts "Login Successful."}
   "# "           {puts "Login Successful."}
   timeout        abort
}
```

Now it can print the message, however after adding this the script just hang there after login succeeded.

Turning on -d option while running it, looks like it's trying to match `""`, not sure how does `puts` results in this? Or what mistake am I making here?

EDIT:
The last few lines of -d output is

```
expect: does " *********# " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no
"Last login:"? no
"# "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "# "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " *********# "
Login Successful too.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "# "? no
```

I replaced something with private info with *********. The next line in my script is

```
expect "# "
```

Comment: can you show the debugging output?

Comment: I added the debugging output, it was trying to match a "", not sure why is that.

Comment: It sounds like the script is expecting "# " again, but that has already been consumed by the block expecting password/last login.etc.  A larger code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Actually the following part will just be like `expect "# " send "...\r"`. Without the block in the question everything works fine, I'm just curious why doesn't the block generate a return and trigger another "# ".